# Can you select the html element or root node with nth-child?

Tags: html, css

I was teaching one of my students about the `nth-child()` pseudo-selector and I asked him: Can you select any possible HTML element with the `nth-child` pseudo-selector? His answer was no, because you cannot select the root node or rather the html element.

I had overlooked this myself because my answer, in the past, had been yes. Is it possible to use `nth-child()` to select the html element? If so, how?

I'd like to know, so when I make definitive claims while teaching my students, they truly are definitive and haven't overlooked any possible corner case.

Thank you

Comment: can you give me an example? I cannot really picture the question in my head today (brain-dead)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo:

> “The :nth-child(an+b) pseudo-class notation represents an element that has an+b-1 siblings before it in the document tree, for any positive integer or zero value of n, **and has a parent element**.”

Answer (score 1):

`nth-child(n)` should select every element. It does, except for the `html` element, which makes sense because `html` is a root element and has no parent. Having a parent element is a requirement as CBroe pointed out.

```css
body {
    border: 5px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
}
html {
    border: 5px dashed red;
}
:nth-child(n) {
    border: 5px dotted blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>first</li>
        <li>second</li>
        <li>kevin</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```